# Is it possible to override the create_migration template in Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I tried placing my custom file in multiple locations inside the lib folder with no success.

I found a PR from 2017 to reactivate this behavior but wasn't merged.
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/13972

I had a look at
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/migration_generator.rb#L17

and it looks like it's not implemented, but I don't know if just this file should change.

I´ve found resources on how to do it in older rails versions, but is there any way to override the Rails templates in Rails 6?

Answer (score -1):

From [this line](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html#customizing-your-workflow-by-changing-generators-templates) of the documentation:

> Since we want to customize Rails::Generators::HelperGenerator, we can do that by simply making a template copy inside lib/templates/rails/helper with the name helper.rb.

In the case for migrations, the template names should be specified as follows (here are the [default templates](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/0ac7b8c843c7b018cbd20df7815e31af9edce53c/activerecord/lib/rails/generators/active_record/migration/templates) for reference):

- `lib/templates/active_record/migration/create_table_migration.rb.tt`
- `lib/templates/active_record/migration/migration.rb.tt`

Comment: This doesn't work.